# How can I load an HTML file?

Tags: objective-c, ios, xcode

How do I load an HTML file into my app (xcode)? I'm using the following code:

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [webView loadRequest:[NSURLRequest requestWithURL:[NSURL fileURLWithPath:[[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"]isDirectory:NO]]]; 
}
```

When I start the app, I only see a white page. What's wrong?

.h file:

```
#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface poules : UIViewController {
    IBOutlet  UIWebView *webView;
}
@property (nonatomic,retain) UIWebView *webView;
@end
```

Comment: your code looks right, is there any debug message in application output pane? and is the webView object connected with it's UI via IB ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is a working example from one of my projects.  My `index.html` file is in a folder called `Documentation/html` in the resources directory. Its important to note that these are "*folder references*", not groups (hence the blue icon):

[image]

then to load it in a `webView`:

```
NSString *resourceDir = [[NSBundle mainBundle] resourcePath];
NSArray *pathComponents = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:resourceDir, @"Documentation", @"html", @"index.html", nil];
NSURL *indexUrl = [NSURL fileURLWithPathComponents:pathComponents];
NSURLRequest *req = [NSURLRequest requestWithURL:indexUrl];
[webView loadRequest:req];
```

Answer (score 0):

try  loadHTMLString:baseURL: method

```
    NSString *html=[NSString stringWithContentsOfFile:your_html_path encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding error:nil];

   [webview loadHTMLString:html baseURL:baseURL];
```

Answer (score 0):

First thing you can check whether your webView is connected or not.

If it is then, you can break down your code to check what is wrong with request that you are trying to load.

1.. Create a NSString for the file path like this, and check if the path is returned or not.

```
NSString *urlString = [[NSBundle mainBundle] pathForResource:@"index" ofType:@"html"];
```

2.. Create a NSURL from the above string like this, and check if the url is correct or nil.

```
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLFromString:urlString];
```

3.. And then create the request.

```
NSURLRequest *request = [NSURLRequest requestFromURL:url];
```